# Task completed: Email Alert

Tags: trigger, tasks, email-alert

I have a Service Cloud in which:

- a User A owns a Case X;
- a User B receives a call about the Case X;
- the User B creates a **task** of type "urge" on the Case X and sets it as "completed" (the User A is not notified about it);
- what I want: an email should be automatically sent to the case owner (User A) alerting him about the "urge" received.

I tried to create a workflow but.... for the task object the option **Email Alert** is not available (for the other objects it is!).

Trigger:

```
trigger SollecitoToMail on Task (after insert, after update) {
//Map<Id, Case> mappa = new Map<Id,Case>();


for(Task t: Trigger.new){


    if(t.subject=='sollecito' && t.status=='Completata'){
        System.debug('Devi mandare la mail');

        //send email to the Case owner
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        //String[] toAddresses = new String[] {address};

    // I choose the EmailTemplate
        EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate Where Name = 'Sollecito' LIMIT 1];
        mail.setTemplateId(et.Id);

    // I have to choose the address. It has to be the address of the Case Owner (the Case related to the Task ==> t.WhatId)


        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(
                             new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });

    } 

}

}
```

Concept: I should create a map 
 of Id and Case, 
save the case related to the task, and then take the mail of the Case owner.

How can I modify the code to implement that?

Comment: yup, this feature still not available. Either you've to code trigger which sends email or would suggest using process builder or flows for same purpose. Also check this app : https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4NIeEAN

Comment: You should also vote on this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpAuAAK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better solution for this is to:

1. Have your Task trigger update a field on Case (`Urgent_Task_Completed__c`) if the Task Owner is not the Case Owner
2. Use a workflow on Case that looks to see if `Urgent_Task_Completed__c` = true
3. Workflow sends email to Case owner and then does field update to set `Urgent_Task_Completed__c` to false

Your existing trigger has a couple of issues:

1. It does a select of emailTemplate within a for loop - will have governor issues with bulk operations
2. It calls `Messaging.sendEmail` in a for loop - you are limited in the number of apex outbound messages you can do per day - and hence should try and use OOB workflow/process builder email alerts whenever possible as they have much larger limits